# PHP - Using OR in IF statement with function

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using OR in if statement 
While adding OR its not working.
Follow the code :

```
if(!exists('vouchers','v_id',$generate_id) OR !exists('vouchers','hash',$generate_hash))
{
     //Doing something
}
```

But when I do only one function call its workes.

```
if(!exists('vouchers','v_id',$generate_id)){//WORK...}
```

exists function :

```
function exists($table,$where,$value){
global $db;
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$where.'='.$value.'');
if($query->num_rows == 0) {
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

}

Any helps to fix my code ?

Comment: Change `OR` to `&&`

Comment: Remove both ! (Not) from condition or Convert OR to &&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the logical AND operator if you want to check the both like :

```
if(!exists('vouchers','v_id',$generate_id) AND !exists('vouchers','hash',$generate_hash)){
___________________________________________^^^
```

Else using the `OR` operator, the code inside condition will be reached if just one of the condition is true.

Comment: I want to check if V_id exists OR hash  exists .
There is a option that v_id not exists but hash exists and then its need to do nothing.

Comment: Then the problem comes from `exists()` function... you need to update your question to show us how you define the logic inside it.

Comment: Uploaded the function